# How to validate Exception messages?

Tags: java, exceptions, runtime

My superior asked me to validate each and every input field in the project that includes the Exception messages. So, am I correct in using Exceptional Handler for validating Exception message.

**ExceptionalHandler**

```
 public class ExceptionHandler {
        public void handle(String s){
        if(s!=null) {
            throw new DBException(s);
        }
        throw new DBException("received null message");
        }
    }
```

**DBException**

```
public class DBException extends RuntimeException {
    public DBException(String s) {
        super(s);
    }
}
```

And I'm calling handle from DBService by something like this

```
.
dh.handle(fileName+" Not Found.");
.
```

So I want to know how to validate Exception messages and also Is there any specific method for calling custom Runtime Exceptions?

Comment: You'll have to ask your boss what he means by "validate". Other than confirming it's a string and it's not empty, I have no way of knowing what your boss considers a "valid" or an "invalid" exception message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation is making sure that something is in the state you expect it to be.

For example, the User enters "a Date".

Of course, users can't actually enter "a Date"; they can only enter the *character representation* of "a Date", in a format "defined" defined by their national/geographical location and/or personal preference (yes; Users can change their own Date format.  Horror!).
Your code must convert that [String] value into a **Date** value but, before you can do that, you ought to check that the entered value *can* be converted from one format to the other.

If it's not in the format you expect, they you might choose to throw an Exception.

Why would you do this? 
The answer is *not* to show an error message to the user.  That's a "last resort" tactic and there may be many better ways of tackling the problem that the user's dodgy typing has caused.  For example, you might just choose to change the background colour of the field to something lurid; that way the user can see there's a problem and fix it, but you don't want your service class method "reaching out" to User Interface code and mucking about with colours.  In this case, you might very well throw a *specific* Exception that describes a[ny] field that contains an invalid value.  If you want to get *really* specific, you might have an Exception for each and every field; possibly overkill.

The User Interface code then catches this Exception and "handles" it, changing the colour of the relevant field.

Where do you *throw* the Exception?  At the point at which your code decides "I can't go any further without breaking".

Where do you *catch* the Exception?  At the point at which your code can do something *useful* with it.  In this case, it's to recolour a field.  In some cases, you write it away to a file (in full) and then show a "friendlier" message to the user.  As a last resort, you might not catch it at all and let the entire program crash and burn (in this case, the Run-Time catches the Exception).

Also (and this is where Exceptions get "interesting") you might be able to take some *corrective* action which would allow your original code to continue *as though the Exception never happened*.  In this case, you might have code within your method that catches the "invalid Date" Exception and, instead, replaces the errant value with, say, today's date.  OK, this is overkill and a simple "if" statement might suffice but, hopefully, you can see the net effect - let the code run as normal; spot if something "exceptional" happens, deal with it, and then carry on).

Note: that's "exceptional", not "unexpected".
You've thought about what *might* happen and put code in to handle that eventuality, on the odd occasion that it might happen.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can have a parser to parse the message of an exception, pass this message to the `ExceptionHandler` class and do some logic on it.

But even better would be to rethink your design. You are most likely forced to handle the message because your exception tree is incorrectly designed.

You want the exception classes to represent the exceptional states, not the exception messages within them.

That way by catching specific exception types (such as `DatabaseConnectionException` or `DatabaseQueryException` instead of a general `DatabaseException`) you already know what went wrong without needing to check the message.

The message can provide additional data, but should not be used as a mean to found out what exactly went wrong. That's what custom exceptional classes are made for.